# path process question

Tags: c#, .net

I have a file name called a.b.c.d
if I use Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension, I get a.b.c, I am wondering how to get **a** part only

Comment: You need to at least, give us an example.

Comment: Of course, this behavior makes sense, because `d` is the only thing Windows is interpreting as the file extension. What you're doing diverges from the intended function of `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` and might be better implemented as simply splitting a string at each period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

```
string p = Path.GFNWE (Path.GFNWE (Path.GFNWE (original)));
```

Option 2:

```
 string p = original;
 int i;
 while ((i = p.LastIndexOf ('.')) > 0) {
      p = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension (p);
 }
```

Option 3: (careful, case-sensitive)

```
 if (original.EndsWith (".b.c.d"))
      original = original.Substring (0, original.Length - ".b.c.d".Length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
var path = "asdf.bsdf.csdf";

while(Path.HasExtension(path))
    path = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
```

Here's another:

```
path = "asdf.bsdf.csdf";
path = path.Substring(0, path.IndexOf('.'));
```

Note that the latter would require a little modification if `path` were actually a path and not just a file name, whereas the first would not.

There are lots of other ways to do this -- these are just two examples.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could try something like

```
Path.GetFileName("a.b.c.d").Split('.')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string fileName = "a.b.c.d";
string whatYouWant = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.IndexOf('.'));
```

Comment: Throws if fileName does not contain any dot.